# using the HTML/source editor in buildfire is stripping out <script>

Tags: buildfire

we are trying to get a very simple script to run in buildfire, but when i post the HTML and script the BuildFire editor strips out everything inside the   is there a way around this? the code is quite simple, i'm not sure why it is being pulled out.

i'm linking to

and my script (which gets removed) lives happily in  ..  and works great on a local HTML page that i build on my desktop and render in chrome.

any advice is welcome!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is done for security purposes. You need to use the BuildFire SDK for any custom development. Learn more in the developer portal https://dev.BuildFire.com it’s free to signup

Or jump into the documentation here https://sdk.buildfire.com/